# populate in sails js return null

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline, populate

i have 2 model user and user_weapon

```js
module.exports = {
tableName: 'user',
autoCreatedAt: false,
autoUpdatedAt: false,
  attributes: {
   Id: {
      type: 'integer',
      unique: true,
      primaryKey: true,
   autoIncrement: true,
      columnName: 'id'
    },
 nickName: {
      type: 'string',
      columnName: 'nickname'
    },
    userName: {
      type: 'string',
      columnName: 'username'
    },
 password: {
      type: 'string',
      columnName: 'password'
    },
 level: {
      type: 'integer',
      columnName: 'level'
    },
 point: {
      type: 'integer',
      columnName: 'point'
    },
 coin: {
      type: 'integer',
      columnName: 'coin'
    },
 heros: {
      type: 'integer',
      columnName: 'heros_id'
    },
 status: {
      type: 'string',
      columnName: 'status'
    }
 ,
 userweapon: {
     collection: 'user_weapon',
      via: 'user'
    }

  }
};
```

and User_weapon.js

```js
/**
* User_weapon.js
*
* @description :: TODO: You might write a short summary of how this model works and what it represents here.
* @docs        :: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models
*/

module.exports = {
tableName: 'user_weapon',
autoCreatedAt: false,
autoUpdatedAt: false,
  attributes: {
   Id: {
      type: 'integer',
      unique: true,
      primaryKey: true,
   autoIncrement: true,
      columnName: 'id'
    },
    weaponLevelId: {
      type: 'integer',
      columnName: 'weaponlevel_id'
    },
   weaponId: {
      type: 'integer',
      columnName: 'weapon_id'
    },
 user: {
   columnName: 'user_id',
   model: 'users'
    }
 
 
 

  }
};
```

when i search user with  and populate User model with User_weapon result is

```
[
  {
    "userweapon": [],
    "password": "1",
    "level": 0,
    "point": 0,
    "coin": 0,
    "status": "online",
    "Id": 3,
    "nickName": "گالا",
    "userName": "1",
    "heros": 1
  }
]
```

why my userweapon is null but in database it is nut null
my User_weapon table is[image]

Comment: Please show the code you use for "search user with and populate User model with User_weapon".

Comment: Users.find({id : 3}).populate('userweapon').exec(function (error, data) {
     sails.log(" error"+error);
   sails.log(" user"+data);
    res.send(data);
   });

Answer (score 0):

In User_weapon.js :

```
 user: {
         columnName: 'user_id',
         model: 'user'
    }
```

the value for model should be user not users

First create the User entry and the get the User ID and create the user_weapon model or if you already have the user_weapon entry update it with the user ID in user columnName of user_weapon.js

```
[
  {
    "userweapon": [
      {
        "Id": 3,
        "weaponLevelId": "25",
        "weaponId": "2",
        "user": 4
      },
      {
        "Id": 4,
        "weaponLevelId": "4",
        "weaponId": "3",
        "user": 4
      }
    ],
    "password": "12345",
    "level": "0",
    "coin": "$",
    "status": "Active",
    "Id": 4,
    "nickName": "priyan",
    "userName": "Anand",
    "heros": 25
  },
  {
    "userweapon": [],
    "password": "12345",
    "level": "0",
    "coin": "$",
    "status": "Active",
    "Id": 5,
    "nickName": "mogu",
    "userName": "Mohan",
    "heros": 25
  }
]
```